# How should I fill Map in abstract mock class?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I don't know how to fill map in abstract class(mocked). I have this architecture:

Abstract class has a member Map:

```
abstract class Parent{

    protected Map<Integer, Example> map;

    protected abstract void methodForChild();

    protected Object doSomthingStaff(){
      Object o = map.get(...);
      //...
   }
}
```

Right now I am testing child class, and I have to mock parent class to call some methods. How can I fill and work with map at parent mocked class ?

I have a setter for this map. But when I am doing next for example:

```
Map<String, Example> mapExample = new HashMap<>();
mapExample.put(putDataHere);
Parent mockParent = Mockito.mock(Parent.class);
mockParent.setMap(mapExample);
```

map is not filled while I am testing.

Should I 100% use Mockito.CALLS_REAL_METHODS or there exists proper way to resolve this problem?

Comment: A child of a class with protected methods can acces and or overwrite these protected things, meaning that the chield can directly insert and gain from the map as long as you unstantiate it first, guess i'll write a quick example

Answer (score 1):

You are getting things wrong.

You surely do **not** mock anything in your abstract parent class when testing a **subclass**.

You strive to test that **subclass**, and you create "ordinary" objects of that class. Like you would do in your production setup.

In other words; the *only* reasonable way how your test should look like is:

```
@Test
public void testWhatever() {
  ChildClass underTest = new ChildClass(...)
  // maybe maybe some underTest.setThis()
  assertThat(underTest.whatever(), is(expected))
```

or something along those lines.

And beyond: try to avoid *protected* fields. If your child class needs to provide certain "input", then do something like

```
abstract class Parent {
  protected abstract Map<Whatever> getMapEntries();
```

which the subclass has to implement then.

Answer (score 1):

> Right now I am testing child class, and I have to mock parent class to
>   call some methods

I wouldn't expect you to mock a *parent* class whilst testing a child class (not sure how you can do that, frankly) I would expect you to mock a class that is being used as a component of a class under test.

Note that this:

```
Parent mockParent = Mockito.mock(Parent.class);
mockParent.setMap(mapExample);
```

won't do anything, since you're calling `setMap()` on a mock, and that won't actually execute anything. I suspect that's your issue.

Comment: ok, I am mocking parent class because child method calling parent method inside itself. In child class: void method ForChild(){doSomthingStaff() } //from parent

Comment: As I told you: don't even think about mocking your parent class. You are going down the wrong rabbit hole.

Comment: This just won't work. What does doSomthingStaff() do. Does *that* contain stuff that needs mocking?

Comment: It gives me some results that I am expecting in child method.

Comment: And how does it derive/provide *those* results ?

Comment: Alright, I think I have to change somthing to avoid fill parent members. I'll try it right now

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good approach to mock the parent class because, in the end, you're mocking the child class, because child inherits the parent's state and behavior (properties and methods). That can never lead to a good test of your code.

Hope this helps. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding how abstract things works in java, they may not be what you want to use, however here i will describe how they work and how to use them, maybe it will better your results, the important part is understanding how `abstract` and `protected` works here

An abstract is a class or interface that has been declared by not defined, as such an abstract class in a case where SOME has been defined, while some is only declared here the childMethod is only declared and the parent method is defined

```
abstract class Parent{
    protected Map<Integer, String> map;

    protected abstract void methodForChild();

    protected void doSomthingStaff(){
        System.out.println("parent print");
    }
}
```

Notice how i can write the parent method here, now the child extends the parent, and defines the rest of the undefined variables/methods

```
public class Child extends Parent {

    @Override
    protected void methodForChild() {
        System.out.println("child print");
    }
}
```

Notice that a child has acces to all PROCTED things directly from it's parent, therefore i can then test it as this

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        Parent child = new Child(); // make the parent using the chield

        child.map = new HashMap<>();
        child.map.put(1, "test1");
        child.map.put(2, "test2");
        child.map.put(3, "test3");

        for(Integer key : child.map.keySet()){
            System.out.println(child.map.get(key));
            child.doSomthingStaff();
            child.methodForChild();
        }

    }
```

which will then print

> test1
>
> parent print
>
> child print
>
> test2
>
> parent print
>
> child print
>
> test3
>
> parent print
>
> child print

Finally notice that in the main, i loop all `Parent` class, because that these can use the methods regardless of how they are defined in the child, if there is say 100 diffrent child classes, you can still loop the all as descriped here

Comment: Thanks for answer